# Jackson JSON Exception

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've written the following:

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object oPOJO = null;

String p_strJSON = "{\"name\" : { \"first\" : \"Joe\", \"last\" : "
    + "\"Sixpack\" },\"gender\" : \"MALE\",\"verified\" : \"false\","
    + "\"userImage\" : \"Rm9vYmFyIQ==\"}";

try
{
    oPOJO = oMapper.readValue(p_strJSON, User.class);
}
catch(Throwable oThrowable)
{
    System.out.println(oThrowable.getMessage());

    throw new RuntimeException(oThrowable);
}
```

And am getting the following exception message when it executes:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3eca90; line: 1, column: 1]

Am I using Jackson incorrectly? I'm using the 1.9.6 JAR - do I need to set anything up in the claspath maybe?

Comment: What is your p_clsType class?

Comment: Sorry about that - example is good to go now

Comment: Is your name object in User defined as a String an "Name" object

Comment: Hard to tell without your implementation of the _User_ class. Your example is lifted from this [Jackson in 5 minutes](http://http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) page. Is your User the same as the one there?

Comment: Missing User object makes this question worthless, and impossible to answer in a useful way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your user class looks something like this, your code passes

```
public class User {
  private Name name;
  private String gender;
  private boolean verified;
  private String userImage;

  // getter and setter
}

public class Name {
  private String first;
  private String last;

  // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joey! Just out of curiosity, why would `name` have to be a `Name` instance? I had it as a String...

Comment: Because when Jackson sees a "{" it is the start of an object. Try visualizing the JSON for example here http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/